# Spring - Hibernate - NoClassDefFoundError CurrentSessionContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up hibernate with spring-boot but I'm stuck at startup with following error:

```
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

My startup code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        //nothing atm.
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= {working_url}
spring.datasource.username={usr}
spring.datasource.password={pass}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Dependencies

[image]

I've looked around the internet and found a few post with the same problem but the solutions didn't help.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing this line in the application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext
```

to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

but M. Deinum raised a good point so I've changed it to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

(leaving out the property raised error: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!)

Could anyone explain the how's and why's it should be the third option? :)

Are my tranactions now 100% managed by Spring? 
Sessions are wired as followed.

```
@Autowired
public CarpoolDOA(SessionFactory sf) {
    this.sf=sf;
}
```

Comment: That will break proper Spring integration ... So it isn't a fix. You are using Spring boot that already sets that property, remove it.